# Delete mapping in solidity

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.8.x

```
    mapping(uint => address) public Players;
```

can anybody help me how can I delete Players mapping. I wrote a lottery contract and I need to remove this mapping to reuse the contract.

I try this code but It doesn't work

```
    delete Players[playerId];
```

Answer (score 2):

Solidity is not like the other languages. You can think of the storage as empty array so even if you have never used a mapping for eg. `Players[12334]` its value is not `nil/null/nullptr` it is the default value for the type. In your case the default value for `address` is the zero address (`0x000...`/`address(0)`). If you want to delete player it is enough to set it to the zero address.

Comment: yeah that works but still there is a problem . Let say my contract has 1 million player , In this case I should use for Loop and equal every address to zero. Is there a way to remove my mapping without using for loop ???

Comment: Unfortunately there is no other way. And deleting all users is a corner case, most probably you will delete only one at a time and you will know which is its index.